# SQL Server query in Delphi joining a table on a linked server

Tags: sql-server, delphi, linked-server

I have a SQL Server database that was recently moved to Azure. I have created a linked server in the local SQL Server to the Azure database. I can run the query in SQL Server Management Studio and it returns the the data I am expecting. When I run this query in my Delphi app I get an error.

> Error: Reference to database and/or server name '...' is not supported in this version of SQL server.

Example of the query I am trying to run.

```
Select t1.field1, t2.field2 
from <linkedserver>.<database>.<dbo>.<table1> t1
join <localserver>.<database>.<dbo>.<table2> t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

Comment: please specify how you are calling in Delphi. If it is working in management studio locally and not working in Delphi, we need to see how you are calling it

Comment: Connections to the database are made using TADOConnection. The query is added to a TADOQuery (TADOQuery.sql.add(select statement)). Query.open.

Comment: Are you using the OLE DB **Driver** for SQL Server or the deprecated Microsoft OLE DB **Provider** for SQL Server? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I have tried both SQLOLEDB and MSOLEDBSQL. SQLOLEDB has been the provider setting in the tadoconnection component.

Answer (score 0):

you must use Native Client for Provider connection type.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP/future readers.